# TimerJob development, what does the EndSecond property of a SPMinuteSchedule mean

Tags: sharepoint, timer-jobs

I'm currently developing on a project which uses some TimerJobs. One of the jobs should check the MySites of some special users about every 2 minutes. So I create a SPMinuteSchedule object and set the BeginSecond property to 0 and the Interval property to 2. I think the use of both properties seem to be obvious but I'm not really sure how to interpret the EndSecond property.

If EndSecond is set to 30 and BeginSecond to 0, does it mean that the Timer Service will start the job some where within these 30 seconds and the job takes as long as it needs to execute its code? Or does it mean that the job can only run for 30 seconds? What happens if the code executed within the Execute() method needs more time to complete?

Whatever might be the answer, the property's name "EndSecond" was not chosen very well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Refer to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc406686.aspx) post for more details to re-iterate below is the info extract from the Post

*Notice how the schedule is set for the timer job. The SPMinuteSchedule.BeginSecond property and the SPMinuteSchedule.EndSecond property specify a start window of execution. The SharePoint Timer service starts the timer job at a random time **between the BeginSecond property and the EndSecond property**. This aspect of the timer service is designed for expensive jobs that execute on all servers in the farm. If all the jobs started at the same time, it could place an unwanted heavy load on the farm. The randomization helps spread the load out across the farm.*